# Change values in DataFrame based on a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe, eg. like below:

```
   Name  Age  Papers
0   tom   10      12
1  nick   15       8
2  juli   14       8
```

And I have a dictionary:

```
d = {10: 11, 14: 30, 20: 44}
```

I want to change values in `df`, such that where `Age` matches any dictionary `d` key, `Papers` should have corresponding value. So, final result should look like this:

```
   Name  Age  Papers
0   tom   10      11
1  nick   15       8
2  juli   14      30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Papers'] = df['Age'].map(d).combine_first(df['Papers']).astype(int)
```

`map` replaces each Age using the dictionary, which adds NaN if the values are missing so we use `combine_first` to add the old values back.

Output:

```
   Name  Age  Papers
0   tom   10      11
1  nick   15       8
2  juli   14      30
```